# Посчитать сумму чисел в каждой строке файла

Tags: c++, файлы, строки

Имеется текстовый файл, содержащий действительные числа. Количество чисел в строке может быть любым, количество строк, не превосходит 100. Нужно вычислить сумму чисел в каждой строке.

Можете посоветовать какой-нибудь способ вытаскивания из файла строк в массив типа int. Пока, для меня это самое логичное решение, или посоветовать что-нибудь альтернативное)

Comment: Построчное чтение из файла вы уже сделали?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Да, сделал

Answer (score 2):

Ну, раз С++, я бы читал файл построчно с помощью `getline`, после чего использовал `istringstream`, из которого с помощью оператора `>>` читал бы и суммировал числа, пока они не закончатся в этом `istringstream`.

А сам файл читал бы, пока не закончатся строки.

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогло, начитался про все это, теперь буду знать!